# Complete metric space, with floor function.

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a problem with this excercise. I need your help.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$

$f(t)=t+[t]$

where $[\cdot]$ is the floor function.

Define the metric:

$$d(x, y)=|f(x)-f(y)|\quad (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$$

1. The metric space $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ is complete?
2. Can $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ be expressed as countable union of its compact subset?

For 1. I think I have to show that a Cauchy sequence is convergent on $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ right?

For 2. I have no idea.

Help me please :)

Comment: For 2. you could try to determine $(\mathbb R, d)$'s compact subsets ...

Comment: For 1., you could try $x_n=1-1/n$. Do you think the sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy? (Yes.) Does it converge?

Comment: For 2., you could try to show that $[k,k+n/(n+1)]$ is compact, for every integers $n\geqslant1$ and $k$.

Comment: This is a typical case where you could write a full solution to your own question.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\langle\mathbb R,d\rangle$ isn’t complete, you’d be better off looking for a Cauchy sequence that *doesn’t* converge. For both parts it may help to prove the following facts.

> 1. If $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0<\epsilon\le 1$, $$B(x,\epsilon)=[x,x+\epsilon)\;.$$
> 2. If $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Z$, and $0<\epsilon\le \min\Big\{x-\lfloor x\rfloor,\lceil x\rceil-x\Big\}$, $$B(x,\epsilon)=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\;.$$

Note that this is almost what happens in $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric; the only points that behave differently are the integers. For (1) you could try to find a $d$-Cauchy sequence that would converge to some integer $n$ in the usual metric but not in this one.

For (2), show that for each integer $n$, the interval $[n,n+1)$ has exactly the same compact subsets in $\langle\mathbb R,d\rangle$ as it has in the usual topology. Is it the union of countably many of these compact subsets?

Comment: @Didier: Thanks; fixed. I inadvertently doubled the fractional part of the other number.

Comment: Right. Now for item 2.

Comment: $B(.5,.75)\ne(-.25,1.25)$.